# Is there a way to get a wordpress user's metadata using an external script

Tags: php

I want to make a script that when it receives a post request with the username and password then it checks if the username and password are correct then it finds the number of coins the user has (i use a plugin called [MoolaMojo](https://co.wordpress.org/plugins/moolamojo/)) and sends it back in a JSON string. The PHP script is under the same domain but is not affiliated with WP.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

// Load Request
$api_method = isset($_POST['api_method']) ? $_POST['api_method'] : '';
$api_data = isset($_POST['api_data']) ? $_POST['api_data'] : '';

// Validate Request
if (empty($api_method) || empty($api_data)) {
    API_Response(true, 'Invalid Request');
}
if (!function_exists($api_method)) {
    API_Response(true, 'API Method Not Implemented');
}

// Call API Method
call_user_func($api_method, $api_data);

/* Helper Function */

function API_Response($isError, $errorMessage, $responseData = '')
{
    exit(json_encode(array(
        'IsError' => $isError,
        'ErrorMessage' => $errorMessage,
        'ResponseData' => $responseData
    )));
}

/* API Methods */

function loginUser($api_data)
{
    // Decode Login Data
    $login_data = json_decode($api_data);

    // Dummy Check
    if ($login_data->username == 'test' &&
        $login_data->password == '1234')
    {
        // Success
        API_Response(false, '', 'SUCCESS');
    }
    else
    {
        // Error
        API_Response(true, 'Invalid username and/or password.');
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: How is this called? You'd probably do better getting an authentication token from WP and using that instead of the username and password every time. And you'd probably do better just building this as a WP REST endpoint. Why is this separate? How were you hoping to get the data from WordPress, over the REST API or directly from the database or something else?

Comment: @Rup I'm calling it from a C# script using a POST request. I haven't ever used authentication tokens or created my own REST endpoint so IDK how to do that. This is separate because I am not able to FTP into the actual website, I just have my own place to FTP into with my own folder. I do not really have any preference on how I get the data as long as I get the data.